# Doctrine 2 Single Computation Exception Error

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I've been trying to make my doctrine 2 setup a modular structure. I receive this error when trying to create an entity:

```
Entity has to be managed for single computation Entities\User@0000000078d19339000000004266cb59
```

Code:

```
/* Test Doctrine */
        $em = Zend_Registry::get('em');
        $user = new Entities\User();
        $user->name = "Bob";
        $user->username = "bob";
        $user->email = "bob@live.com";
        $user->password = "test";
        $user->activation = "";
        $em->flush($user);
        $em->persist();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

God dammit...

I embarrassed myself! This is a golden rule problem...

the fix:

```
/* Test Doctrine */
        $em = Zend_Registry::get('em');
        $user = new Entities\User();
        $user->name = "Bob";
        $user->username = "bob";
        $user->email = "bob@live.com";
        $user->password = "test";
        $user->activation = "";
        $em->persist($user); // The other way around :D
        $em->flush();
```